# Regexp Remove any non alphanumeric, but leave some special characters in one expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code that replaces all non alphanumeric characters with "-" char.

```
return Regex.Replace(strIn, @"[\W|_]+", "-", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but I need to change it to allow pass some special characters (one or more) for example: #,*,%

how to change this regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, you can use charcter class subtraction<sup>[info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xmlcharclass.html#subtract)</sup>, for example to remove `#` from the character class:

```
[\W_-[#]]+
```

Just add other accepted special chars after the `#`. Live example here: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=YFQ40277

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
[^\p{L}\p{N}#*%]+
```

This matches one or more characters that are neither letters nor digits nor any of `#`, `*` or `%`.

Comment: couldn't make it work :(  : `parsing "[^\pL\pN#*%]+" - Malformed \p{X} character escape.`

Comment: Try `[^\p{L}\p{N}#*%]+`.  It's supposed to work without the braces when the property name is just one letter, but in .NET they seem to be required when it's inside another character class like this.

Comment: Ah yes, it seems that .NET requires the more verbose `\p{L}` syntax. Will update.

Comment: Correction: .NET seems to require the braces *all* the time.  How disappointing!

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9#*%]+
```

If you are using unicode you can do (as Tim's answer):

```
[^\p{L}\p{N}#*%]+
```

Comment: Depends on whether you think `Ä` is a letter or not. .NET does think so and includes it in `\w`.

Comment: if the text is in russian that will not work (and it really is)

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

`([^\w#*%]|_)`

Add any other special characters after the %.

It is basically saying, match any character that is not (^) a word character(\w), #, * or % OR match _.

Comment: What about the underscore? It's not allowed now but it was allowed in the OP's regex.

Comment: this is not working good it leaves me a lot of "-" characters :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems this way is the best solution for you

```
@"(?!.*[^\w#*%])"
```

Comment: I don't think so.  `(?!.*[^\w#*%])` means, "looking forward from the current position, there is not a character that does not match `[\w#*%]`".  It doesn't require any characters to be present, so it will always match, and it doesn't *consume* any characters, so it can't be used to remove anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set subtraction for that:

```
@"[\W_-[#*%]]+"
```

This matches the set of all non-word characters and the underscore, *minus* the set of `#`, `*` and `%`.

Note that you don't have to use `|` for "or" in a character class, since that's implied.  In fact, the `|` in your regex just matches `|`.

Note also that in .NET, `\w` matches a few other "connector punctuation" characters besides the underscore.  If you want to match the other characters too, you can use

```
@"[\W\p{Pc}-[#*%]]+"
```